# Dropzone in react JS

Tags: reactjs, dropzone.js

I am willing to implement a dropzone to upload images and pdf files. There are two file field buttons. One is supposed to upload only images and other is suppose to upload the only pdf files.

Best shot I gave is:

```
myDropzone = new Dropzone("#drop-zone", {
        url: "/file/post",
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        init: function () {
            this.options.acceptedFiles = '.pdf'
        });

$('#add_custom_logo_button, #add_pdf_file_button').on('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        component.setState({acceptFiles: $(this).data('file-accepts')});
    });
```

HTML Element:

```
<div id="drop-zone" className="dropzone" data-file-accepts={this.state.acceptFiles}/>
<label class='control-label' for='add_custom_logo'>Custom Logo Image</label>
<button type='button'id='add_custom_logo_button' data-file-accepts="image/*"></button>
<div>
 <label class="control-label for="add_custom_logo" data-file-accepts="application/pdf">PDF File</label> 
 <label class="label-button" id="add_pdf_file_button">
   <span>Upload File </span>
 </label>
</div>
```

Here `acceptFiles` is I have mentioned an option in the state of the component.
How can I restrict accepted file types for each file field?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create two differents dropzone areas, and assign the accepted files to each as per your requisites. To allow only images and consider all the formats I think this option will be better.

```
acceptedFiles: '.png,.jpg,.jpeg',
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay so basically I need to create different component for dropzone that accepts pdf files?

Comment: Two dropzone areas, and in your settings, assign the one that will accept only pdf and the other images. For example, leave the one that accepts pdf and create another mockup for you dropzone area that will accept images. I think that will be optimus way to solve it.